# Pyinstaller and seaborn

Tags: python, pyinstaller, seaborn

I am trying to deploy an application and it crashes when importing seaborn

Here is my config: Python 2.7, pyinstaller 3.3.1, seaborn 0.8.1.

Here is the simplest piece of code to reproduce I wrote in installTest.py

```
import seaborn
print 'It works now!'
```

Then in console I typed `pyinstaller .\installTest`

I get a long error code terminating with a `messagesstream` module not found.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: As a start, it would be useful to show people the long error you get.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

First here is what makes the little example work: I modify my .spec file to include some hidden imports and some pandas and seaborn stuff

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

def get_seaborn_path():
    import seaborn
    seaborn_path = seaborn.__path__[0]
    return seaborn_path
def get_pandas_path():
    import pandas
    pandas_path = pandas.__path__[0]
    return pandas_path


a = Analysis(['installTest.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Admin\\PycharmProjects\\InstalTest'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['scipy._lib.messagestream',     'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas '],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)

dict_tree = Tree(get_seaborn_path(), prefix='seaborn', excludes=["*.pyc"])
dict_tree2 = Tree(get_pandas_path(), prefix='pandas', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += dict_tree
a.datas += dict_tree2
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'seaborn' not in x[0], a.binaries)
a.binaries += filter(lambda x: 'pandas' not in x[0], a.binaries)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='installTest',
          debug=True,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='installTest')
```

Comment: have you found any alternatives to this approach? I am building my app with fbs, which does not allow any modification of the spec file (it is autogenerated during freeze). Implementing the mentioned two hidden imports is possible, but this alone does not lead to a functional binary.