# Pyinstaller EXE crashes at Seaborn relplot when ran from cmd but runs in Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pyinstaller, executable

I've created an executable with Pyinstaller. Running the executable from cmd, it crashes when it starts creating the relplot. For creating the exe, I used this command:`pyinstaller test.py --onefile`. Here is test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import seaborn as sns

print('###################relplot##########################')
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day")
g.fig.savefig('.\\test.png')
print('success')
```

Conda info:

```
shell level : 2
conda version : 4.9.2
conda-build version : 3.20.5
python version : 3.8.5.final.0
virtual packages : __cuda=11.1=0
                   __win=0=0
                   __archspec=1=x86_64
platform : win-64
user-agent : conda/4.10.1 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.8.8 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
administrator : False
netrc file : None
offline mode : False
```

[Pyinstaller warning file when the .exe is built.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oQiRCiSGHRg0xDaucCs7uGIt-cMIGJfw/view?usp=sharing)

[Pyinstaller debug messages at runtime](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w-5ws-pJCOam5OKzK__Y_-kqkQ_XaWRx/view?usp=sharing) with `--debug=imports` See at the bottom where it crashes.

I have tried updating the environment and the libraries, writing crazy .spec file found here and there. nothing seems to work. I am aware of [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135676/pyinstaller-and-seaborn) But The solution doesn't work, the question has not gotten much attention and it is incomplete and I cannot leave comments for it and to me it seems to be slightly different than my issue.

**Update:** The exe file runs with no problem in the Anaconda Prompt, but it crashes in the cmd. I tried the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580791/pyinstaller-exe-fails-to-execute-numpy-operation-when-run-from-command-prompt-bu) and it did not work.

Conda virtual environment Python 3.7.10:

```
name: test_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - altgraph=0.17=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - ca-certificates=2021.1.19=haa95532_1
  - certifi=2020.12.5=py37haa95532_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py37_0
  - freetype=2.10.4=hd328e21_0
  - future=0.18.2=py37_1
  - icc_rt=2019.0.0=h0cc432a_1
  - icu=58.2=ha925a31_3
  - intel-openmp=2020.2=254
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - kiwisolver=1.3.1=py37hd77b12b_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=h2a8f88b_0
  - macholib=1.14=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - matplotlib=3.2.2=0
  - matplotlib-base=3.2.2=py37h64f37c6_0
  - mkl=2020.2=256
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py37h196d8e1_0
  - mkl_fft=1.3.0=py37h46781fe_0
  - mkl_random=1.1.1=py37h47e9c7a_0
  - numpy=1.19.2=py37hadc3359_0
  - numpy-base=1.19.2=py37ha3acd2a_0
  - openssl=1.1.1k=h2bbff1b_0
  - pandas=1.2.3=py37hf11a4ad_0
  - pefile=2019.4.18=py_0
  - pip=21.0.1=py37haa95532_0
  - pycryptodome=3.10.1=py37h2bbff1b_0
  - pyinstaller=3.6=py37h8cc25b3_6
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py37h6538335_2
  - python=3.7.10=h6244533_0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pytz=2021.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - pywin32=227=py37he774522_1
  - pywin32-ctypes=0.2.0=py37_1001
  - qt=5.9.7=vc14h73c81de_0
  - scipy=1.6.2=py37h14eb087_0
  - seaborn=0.10.1=py_0
  - setuptools=52.0.0=py37haa95532_0
  - sip=4.19.8=py37h6538335_0
  - six=1.15.0=py37haa95532_0
  - sqlite=3.35.4=h2bbff1b_0
  - tornado=6.1=py37h2bbff1b_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - wheel=0.36.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py37_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h62dcd97_4
prefix: C:\Users\alina\.conda\envs\test_env
```

Comment: Did you try the same with some code with less dependencies? Maybe just `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.show()`? Did you read the most important comment in the linked post: `As a start, it would be useful to show people the long error you get.`?  Please don't post error messages as image, but as text.

Comment: I created an environment with seaborn only in it, and an script with only seaborn imported in it. The exe failed to execute but it didn't crash like this example. BTW, I did  add the messages, but they exceeded the max number of characters. So here it is the link to the txt files with the debug messages and warning messages.

Comment: Well, my question is about only using matplotlib.  Seaborn is an extension to matplotlib and pandas.  So, please create a test with only matplotlib to check whether that works or not.

Comment: @JohanC thank you for you suggestions. I did what you said. I got the error addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63103147/could-not-find-the-matplotlib-data-files) and resolved it by downgrading to matplotlib 3.2.2. I simplified the script's imported libraries like you said and actually used relplot. The executable still crashes at the relplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing I realized this only happens when I use `conda` environment for creating my executables. I simply created a `venv` rather than a `conda` environment and everything went well. I suggest to stay away from the `conda` environment if possible when you want to distribute your Python app using `pyinstaller`.